# the method addHeader (String, String) is undefined for the type HttpGet

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have this program:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class ApplicationRESTFul {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    }

}
```

But I got this message from eclipse

```
the method addHeader (String, String) is undefined for the type HttpGet
```

I am using this library and as I see in the documentation , the method should exist (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5)

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: Do you have any other imports with a class called `HttpGet`?

Comment: Try this: `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet request = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet(url);`

Comment: I got the same error :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

importing the depency from maven instead to add the lib in the classpath solved the problem

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding httpcore JAR to class path. Adding the dependency from maven adds the httpcore JAR too and not just the httpclient JAR, and that's why it works too.